# Ruby synchronisation: How to make threads work one after another in proper order?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, synchronization, mutex, monitor

My problem is that I don't know how synchronise multiple threads using Ruby. The task is to create six threads and start them immediately. All of them should do some work (for example `puts "Thread 1" Hi"`) one after another in the order I need it to work.

### I've tried to work with Mutex, Monitor and Condition Variable, but all of them worked in random order. Could anybody explain how to achieve my goal?

After some time of struggling with Mutex and Condition Variable I've achieved my goal.
This code is a little bit messy, and I intentionally did't use cycles for "clearer view".

```
cv = ConditionVariable.new
mutex = Mutex.new

mutex2 = Mutex.new
cv2 = ConditionVariable.new

mutex3 = Mutex.new
cv3 = ConditionVariable.new

mutex4 = Mutex.new
cv4 = ConditionVariable.new

mutex5 = Mutex.new
cv5 = ConditionVariable.new

mutex6 = Mutex.new
cv6 = ConditionVariable.new



Thread.new do
  mutex.synchronize {
    puts 'First: Hi'
    cv.wait(mutex)
    puts 'First: Bye'
    #cv.wait(mutex)
    cv.signal
    puts 'First: One more time'
  }

end

Thread.new do
  mutex.synchronize {
    puts 'Second: Hi'
    cv.signal
    cv.wait(mutex)
    puts 'Second:Bye'
    cv.signal
  }

  mutex2.synchronize {
    puts  'Second: Starting third'
    cv2.signal

  }
end

Thread.new do
  mutex2.synchronize {
    cv2.wait(mutex2)
    puts 'Third: Hi'
  }

  mutex3.synchronize {
    puts 'Third: Starting forth'
    cv3.signal
  }
end

Thread.new do
  mutex3.synchronize {
    cv3.wait(mutex3)
    puts 'Forth: Hi'
  }

  mutex4.synchronize {
    puts 'Forth: Starting fifth'
    cv4.signal
  }
end

Thread.new do
  mutex4.synchronize {
    cv4.wait(mutex4)
    puts 'Fifth: Hi'
  }

  mutex5.synchronize {
    puts 'Fifth: Starting sixth'
    cv5.signal
  }
end

Thread.new {
  mutex5.synchronize {
    cv5.wait(mutex5)
    puts 'Sixth:Hi'
  }
}

sleep 2
```

Comment: If you want them to work serially, why do you use threads?

Comment: @UriAgassi i am learning multithreading, it is part of the task. The thing is that I can't achieve needed result.

Comment: Please, learn how to use threads *properly* before you even try to make them work bizarrely.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz ok, but how to preserve order in multithreading? isn't it the purpose of synchronisation?

Comment: NO! Synchronization is not about order, it is about _critical sections_ where you don't want more than one thread touching the same resource at same time, so it won't create inconsistencies

Comment: No. The purpose of synchronization is to *permit* concurrent operation. Ordering should be handled other ways. (For example, don't arrange to have work done at all until that work needs to be done.)

Comment: Most of the commentators have too narrow a definition of what synchronization is.  While synchronization is often about critical sections, it isn't always.  Sometimes it _is_ about making sure that B happens after A.

Comment: @WayneConrad Making B happen after A isn't synchronization. Make sure I don't put on my shoes before my socks doesn't require synchronization. It just requires that no command to put on my shoes is emitted until my socks are on. Sequencing is not really synchronization.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Making B happen after A is _Serialization_," which is a kind of synchronization.  Keeping two things from happening at the same time is _Mutual Exclusion_, which is also a kind of synchronization.  For one (but not the only) source of these definitions, please see [The little book of Semaphores](http://greenteapress.com/semaphores/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Using Queue as a PV Semaphore

You can abuse [Queue](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/thread/rdoc/Queue.html), using it like a traditional [PV Semaphore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29).  To do this, you create an instance of Queue:

```
require 'thread'
...
sem = Queue.new
```

When a thread needs to wait, it calls [Queue#deq](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/thread/rdoc/Queue.html#method-i-deq):

```
# waiting thread
sem.deq
```

When some other thread wants to unblock the waiting thread, it pushes something (anything) onto the queue:

```
# another thread that wants to unblock the waiting thread
sem.enq :go
```

## A Worker class

Here's a worker class that uses Queue to synchronize its start and stop:

```
class Worker

  def initialize(worker_number)  
    @start = Queue.new
    Thread.new do
      @start.deq
      puts "Thread #{worker_number}"
      @when_done.call
    end
  end

  def start
    @start.enq :start
  end

  def when_done(&block)
    @when_done = block
  end

end
```

When constructed, a worker creates a thread, but that thread then waits on the `@start` queue.  Not until #start is called will the thread unblock.

When done, the thread will execute the block that was called to #when_done.  We'll see how this is used in just a moment.

### Creating workers

First, let's make sure that if any threads raise an exception, we get to find out about it:

```
Thread.abort_on_exception = true
```

We'll need six workers:

```
workers = (1..6).map { |i| Worker.new(i) }
```

### Telling each worker what to do when it's done

Here's where #when_done comes into play:

```
workers.each_cons(2) do |w1, w2|
  w1.when_done { w2.start }
end
```

This takes each pair of workers in turn.  Each worker *except the last* is told, that when it finishes, it should start the worker after it.  That just leaves the last worker.  When it finishes, we want it to notify this thread:

```
all_done = Queue.new
workers.last.when_done { all_done.enq :done }
```

### Let's Go!

Now all that remains is to start the first thread:

```
workers.first.start
```

and wait for the last thread to finish:

```
all_done.deq
```

The output:

```
Thread 1
Thread 2
Thread 3
Thread 4
Thread 5
Thread 6
```

Comment: thank you, very nice solution! But do you know how to achieve the same result using monitor or semaphore?

Comment: @RomaBugaian Ruby does not, as far as I know, have a semaphore.  That's why I used Queue, which can behave like a semaphore.  I don't know how to do this using a monitor--monitors don't seem well suited for serialization.

Comment: Ruby has class Mutex that implements semaphore, so it should behave like classic semaphore

Comment: @Roma, Good point.  Mutex is a _little_ like a classic PV semaphore, but not a whole lot.  Mutex is only locked or unlocked; this is equivalent to a PV semaphore which count can be only 0 or 1.  Also, a Mutex starts out unlocked (if a PV semaphore, it would have a count of 1).

Comment: @Roma I was just trying to rewrite this example using Mutex, and it's worse than I thought: A locked Mutex can only be unlocked by the same thread that locked it.  You can't use a Mutex as a PV semaphore.

Comment: I've edited my question, and added the result I've achieved my using Mutex and Condition Variable

Answer (score 1):

If you're just getting started with threads, you might want to try something simple. Let the 1st thread sleep for 1 second, the 2nd for 2 seconds, the 3rd for 3 seconds and so on:

```
$stdout.sync = true

threads = []
(1..6).each do |i|
  threads << Thread.new {
    sleep i
    puts "Hi from thread #{i}"
  }
end

threads.each(&:join)
```

Output (takes 6 seconds because the threads run in parallel):

```
Hi from thread 1
Hi from thread 2
Hi from thread 3
Hi from thread 4
Hi from thread 5
Hi from thread 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign each a number, which will denote its place in the queue, and check it to see whose turn it is:

```
class QueuedWorker

  def initialize(mutex, condition_variable, my_turn)
    @mutex = mutex
    @my_turn = my_turn
    @condition_variable = condition_variable
  end

  def self.turn
    @turn ||= 0
  end

  def self.done
    @turn = turn + 1
  end

  def run
    loop do
      @mutex.synchronize do
        if QueuedWorker.turn == @my_turn
          # do actual work
          QueuedWorker.done
          @condition_variable.signal
          return
        end
        @condition_variable.signal
        @condition_variable.wait(@mutex)
      end
    end
  end
end

mutex = Mutex.new
cv = ConditionVariable.new

(0..10).each do |i|
  Thread.new do
    QueueWorker.new(mutex, cv, i).run
  end
end
```

That being said, the implementation is awkward, since threading are specifically *not* built for serial work. If you need something to work serially, do it in a single thread.